# NSTableView rows using NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsarray

I need to Write 4 sections in a table where two of them have only a single row.

So is there any other way i could do it instead of using NSArray for just a single row?

Comment: What do you mean by other way??? you can take variables... or directly fetch from other place or use NSMutableArray...  Please clarify you question for any further doubt

Comment: As i have a very little knowledge on objective-C. i am using nsarray for creating a single row in section.. i want to create a row without using this nsarray

Comment: but then you can put some more code and ask what problems do you face while using NSArray...

Comment: What would you like to put into these rows? If its only simple text you can create an NSString and assign it to your cell's textlabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two dimensional array using NSMutablearray

You can access them by using

```
[[array objectAtIndex: ] objectAtIndex: ]
```

Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 0):

Dont know from where you are getting the data for your 2 single rows but you could make a switch(indexPath.section)/case or an if(indexpath.section == yoursectionnumber) logic  in your cellForRowAtIndexPart delegate method and there you can assign a value to your cell.

As DShah wrote, you can use variables and such for this so you could for example do a `cell.textLabel.text = myString;`
Where myString is an NSString created by you.